# Trac PHP Syntax Highlighting not working in Wiki

Tags: php, syntax-highlighting, wiki, trac, pygments

Syntax highlighting for PHP ***refuses*** to work on Wiki pages in my installation of Trac.  It works beautifully when browsing source, but not in the Wiki. Javascript, C, and Python syntax highlighting work in the Wiki, but not PHP. Woe is me.

I have `Trac 0.11.7` installed on `Ubuntu 10.04`. My web server is `Apache 2.2.14`.

I have manually installed Pygments.  No luck. I have changed the Pygments Theme in preferences. No luck.

I have absolutely 0 errors logged in the `trac` and `apache` logs. Logging level for Trac is set to `WARNING` (and Trac logging is working - I have other errors from earlier today). Firebug also displays no error with everything turned on (except one unrelated "Unknown property '-moz-opacity'" CSS error).

Viewing the HTML source of the page shows that the code is simply spit out as preformatted text. It does not have the tons of `<span>`'s all other syntax-highlighted code blocks have.

This is the code I'm using in the Wiki:

```
{{{
#!php
if(true)
{
    echo 'hi';
}
}}}
```

And this is the result:

```
<div class="code"><pre><span class="x">if(true)
{
    echo 'hi';
}
</span></pre></div>
```

Please help :-)

---

For an example of what I would expect, here's some JS code that works:

```
{{{
#!js
if(true)
{
    alert('hi');
}
}}}
```

And this is the result:

```
<div class="code"><pre><span class="k">if</span><span class="p">(</span><span class="kc">true</span><span class="p">)</span>
<span class="p">{</span>
    <span class="nx">alert</span><span class="p">(</span><span class="s1">'hi'</span><span class="p">);</span>
<span class="p">}</span>
</pre></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can resolve this by including the `<?php` tag:

```
{{{
#!php
<?php
if(true)
{
    echo 'hi';
}
}}}
```

That works for me on my Trac wiki, anyhow.  I still haven't been able to determine if this is intended behavior or a bug, though.

Comment: Worth also mentioning that syntax highlighting only works if Trac has certain extra packages installed. Quote: "[To activate syntax coloring, simply install either one (or more) of these packages...](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracSyntaxColoring)"

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why this always happens to me.  Of course I figure it out 5 minutes after posting the question.

The problem was that I didn't have `<?php ?>` in the php source, so the syntax-highlighter was treating it like HTML; just like the PHP parser.

C, Python, and JS don't have an equivalent, so that's why they seemed to work when PHP didn't.

This code works:

```
{{{
#!php
<?php
if(true)
{
    echo 'hi';
}
?>
}}}
```

I'm leaving this question here in case anyone else has the same problem, despite how stupid I feel.